# Can we write/prepare Fixed Width Length file type in Nifi?

Tags: transform, apache-nifi, file-format

I have an input JSON, and I want to convert that JSON to a Fixed width length file format.

I wanted to know if there is any way I can convert the JSON file to Fixed Width length file format in Nifi, either by using some processor or property while writing the records.

The Fixed width length file format is text format.

Here is the sample Input Json

```
[
  {
    "orderId": "1234567890",
    "orderName": "Test1"
  },
  {
    "orderId": "12235",
    "orderName": "Test2"
  },
  {
    "orderId": "12236",
    "orderName": "Test3"
  }
]
```

Here is the expected output:

```
1234567890 Test1     
12235      Test2     
12236      Test3
```

Any leads would be helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-scripting-nar/1.20.0/org.apache.nifi.record.script.ScriptedRecordSetWriter/index.html and https://alasdairb.com/2021/09/21/getting-started-with-nifis-scriptedreader-by-processing-key-value-pairs-part-1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have since figured out a way to do this without writing a custom Record Writer.  I used ConvertRecord processor, from JSONTreeReader to FreeFormTextRecordSetWriter.  The JSON looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "userId": "68156",
        "firstName": "Vesta",
        "lastName": "Herzog"
    },
    {
        "userId": "64191",
        "firstName": "Jenifer",
        "lastName": "Bosco"
    }
]
```

Then, configure the Text property of the FreeFormTextRecordSetWriter as such:

```
${userId:padRight(10,' ')}${lastName:padRight(15,' ')}${firstName:padRight(15,' ')}
```

This generates a 40 character wide fixed width file, with the userID starting at character 1, lastname starting at character 11, and firstname starting at character 26.

```
68156     Herzog        Vesta
64191     Jenifer       Bosco
```

A generic fixed width file writer that could be configured would be far better, particularly if you have multiple fixed width formats to generate.  However, this gets the job done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Walker White!
I have also figured it out using FreeFormTextRecordSetWriter and I used JoltTransform processor to add the required padding!

Comment: I'd be very interested in how you setup the JoltTransform, if you're willing to share it, as my solution above is not very supportable.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your JSON input is going to be relatively flat you could use the [ConvertRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.21.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ConvertRecord/index.html) processor

[image: Sample Flow]

[image: ConvertRecord Properties]

Setup a `JsonTreeReader` and a `CSVRecordSetWriter` and you should get the resulting output flowfile as below

[image]

> Note: You can tweak the `CSVRecordSetWriter` properties if you want to exclude the headerline

Comment: Hi @DataWrangler,
Thanks for your comment. But if I use CSVRecordSetWriter, it will simply write it in the CSV.
It will not create a fixed-width length file. I want to have trailing spaces in the field values if the length of the value is less than the required length of the field.

Answer (score 0):

I have since discovered what I considered a far more supportable solution using `ScriptedTransformRecord`.  Reminder that the JSON looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "userId": "68156",
        "firstName": "Vesta",
        "lastName": "Herzog"
    },
    {
        "userId": "64191",
        "firstName": "Jenifer",
        "lastName": "Bosco"
    }
]
```

Then, I set up a `ScriptedTransformRecord` as such:
[image]

The FixedWidthWriter is an instance of a `FreeFormTextRecordSetWriter`, which is configured as:
[image]

The Python file (str.py) looks like this:

```
fieldMap = (
  {
      "name": "userId",
      "length": 10
  },
  {
      "name": "firstName",
      "length": 15
  },
  {
      "name": "lastName",
      "length": 15
  }
)

rowData = ""
for rec in fieldMap:
    rowData = rowData + record.getAsString( rec['name'] ).ljust( rec['length'], ' ')

record.setValue('rowData', rowData )

_ = record
```

The code loops through the `fieldMap` (which is an ordered list), pulling the JSON value by name and padding it based upon the length.  We're using the built in variable `record` (Record class) which holds the content, adding an attribute `rowData` to the flow file, which is then written by the `FreeFormTextRecordSetWriter`.

This approach has two large benefits, which are 1) creating multiple `fieldMap`s for differnt output formats that can be read in, and 2) allowing us to put both the Python code and the `fieldMap`s under source control, and not embedded in the processor.

To be honest, I believe there must be a more efficient way by writing a custom Record Writer class, or even a `ScriptedRecordSetWriter`.  However, I could not find any examples or documentation.  That said, this works MUCH better than my last attempt.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this @Walker White.
But as I mentioned in the earlier comment I used Jolt to add the trailing spaces and the FreeFormTextRecordSetWriter to just put the values.

Comment: In JoltTransformJSON processor, we can use the rightPad function in modify-overwrite-beta operation.

Comment: If yo want I can share more details on JoltTransformJSON processor, Jolt and how I used FreeFormTextRecordSetWriter.